# Using continuity to prove an integral implication

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous such that $f\ge0$.

Prove the following is true:

$\int_a^b f=0 \implies f=0$

Then, state if the result is still true when $f$ is not continuous.

--

I am unsure of where to start with this proof really. I know that since $f$ is continuous then it must be integrable but can't see a direction to take this in. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Start from the fact that $f \ge 0$ and is continuous...

Comment: For the second part, think about Lebesgue measure zero...

Comment: Show that if $f(x_0) >0 $ for some $x_0$ that there is some $\delta>0$ such that $f(x) > {1 \over 2} f(x_0)$ for $x \in B(x_0,\delta)$.

Comment: I was thinking maybe that since $f$ is continuous at $y$ and $f(y)>0$ then $\exists [c,d] \subset [a,b]$ and I could also set $\lambda >0$ such that $f(x) \ge \lambda$ for $x\in[c,d]$

Answer (score 3):

If $f\neq 0$, there is $x\in (a,b)$ s.t. $f(x)>0$. Then, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $[x-\delta ,x+\delta ]\subset (a,b)$ and $f|_{(x-\delta ,x+\delta )}\geq m>0$ for some $m$. Then $$\int_a^b f\geq \int_{x-\delta }^{x+\delta } f>0\geq 2m\delta >0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your argument 'since $f$ is continuous then it must be integrable' is WRONG!. $f$ is integrable since it is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$.

FTC is another method you could use.

Define $F$ such that, $$F(x) = \int_a^x \, f(x) \,dx$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

From FTC, $F^{\prime}(x) = f(x)$. Since $f\geq 0$, it turns out that $F$ is non-decreasing on $[a,b]$. By construction,  $F(b) = F(a) =0$. Hence, $F$ must be a constant function. This implies that $f = 0$.

For part (II), consider Thomae's function on $[0,1]$, which is zero almost everywhere and has countably many discontinuities. Hence, $f$ is integrable and $\int f = 0$ but $f \neq 0$.

Comment: *'since  is continuous then it must be integrable' is WRONG* This is obviously wrong ! Riemann integrability is always on compact set.